# filter to remove external links from text

Tags: 7, input-formats

Do you know about a way to automatically remove external links after user submits node? I want to keep only internal ones. I am not able to find any text filter or module which does that. Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own [filter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.api.php/function/hook_filter_info/7) and use function [url_is_external](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url_is_external/7)

As an example you can check filter "filter_url" in module filter (available in drupal core)

Comment: I've created a filter, but how do I apply url_is_external to the body content?

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra I think this can help https://www.drupal.org/node/213156